# Why are there two locations for SharePoint and why don't they show the same files?

Tags: sync, office365, onedrive, sharepoint, microsoft-onedrive

On my SharePoint I have synced it with my local drive and I see two locations.

```
https://yellowshoe.sharepoint.com/sites/HR/Shared Documents/SFB Consulting
```

```
Z:\One Drive Square Balloon\Yellowshoe Technology LLC\HR - Documents\SFB Consulting
```

Weirdly if I save to the first one, the second one doesn't show the file.  I guess it could be a sync issue, but I open the file from the second URL.  I'd rather save it there so I can use the file straight away and let any sync take place in the background.

I solve this by using file save as but it's not a great workflow to have to do this over and over again for multiple files.

Is there a better workflow or a way to make this work the way I want to?

As a secondary question but it's probably related.  If I create a new folder locally and then try to save the document it won't let me for like 5-10 minutes which is frustrating.  I think this is syncing with SharePoint.  But if I create the document in that folder it's already saved and I can work on it and save it there no issues.  Is there a way to avoid the 5 minute wait?  It's also a poor workflow and leaves documents unsaved for 5 minutes.

I'm using Windows 10 as my OS.
OneDrive version: Build 23.061.0319.0001 (64-bit)

Comment: Please add more details like the name an version of the operative system that you are using as well the version of the OneDrive apps that installed in your computer. It's possible that you have more than one, one for users not having a Office / Microsoft 365 account and another for Office / Microsoft 365 accounts. It might be possible too that you have more than two due to problems during install/update or who knows what other weird thing could happen. Regarding the scondary question, please bear in mind that posts should include only one question.

Comment: @Rubén I was wondering if the second question was related, hence my including it, but you're right I can start another question for that.  I've updated my answer with the information requested.  I do have 2 OneDrives, a personal and a work one, but that is not the issue.  You can kind of see from the URLs that I have mapped them with sync.